# Как во всплывающем окне получить данные из БД?

Tags: javascript, php, html

На странице имеется табличка. При клике на одну из строк, я получаю id этой строки из БД в переменную JavaScript (точнее этот id уже вынесен в таблицу в спрятанном столбце). Затем, есть кнопа для редактирования этой строки, которая открывает форму редактирования во всплывающем окне. Как мне в этой форме отобразить данные из таблицы?

```js
$fordel=$(this).children('td:last-child').text();
$fordell=$(this).children('td:first-child').text();
```

Вот таким образом получаю данные из нарисованной таблицы. Но можно только 1й и последний столбец. Или всё таки можно получить так из любого столбца?

Answer (score 1):

В *Jquery* есть метод **[eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** можно использовать его, например.

```
$(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
```

В данном пример будет взят текст из ячейки третьей по счёту (счёт идёт с нуля)

---

Можно пробежаться по `td` циклом и тогда `eq` вообще не нужен

Comment: Вроде бы это сделал, теперь значение из любой ячейки строки могу взять. Но как теперь эти значения перенести в HTML форму?

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «Задать вопрос». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Пометьте td-элементы специальными классами или атрибутами и выбирайте ячейки по этим меткам.

Но вообще, если ваша задача -- заполнить форму данными существующей записи из бд. То в общем случае удобнее получить нужные данные, выполнив запрос к бэку (AJAX-запрос). В этом случае совершенно неважно, есть ли все необходимые данные у вас на странице.

Допустим у меня в бд есть записи товаров:

| id | name | descriptionMarkdown | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | бутылка кефира | - белки: 3 - жиры: 3,4 - углеводы: 4 | 13600 |
| 2 | полбатона | - белки: 7,5 - жиры: 2,9 - углеводы: 51,4 | 2500 |

Здесь описание товара в [markdown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), а на странице будет выводится HTML. Мы не сможем получить исходное описание, забирая данные со страницы. Нужен запрос к бэку.

На бэке надо сделать ручку, которая будет возвращать запись по id в JSON-формате

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "полбатона",
    "descriptionMarkdown": "- белки: 7,5\n- жиры: 2,9\n- углеводы: 51,4",
    "price": 2500
}
```

Остаётся сделать запрос и установить эти данные в качестве значений соответствующих инпутов формы.

---

Научится делать запросы на бек вам поможет [учебник на javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch). Ну или используйте $.ajax.